# Does a Mercenary run's Life Insurance pay back money that is in town before a run?

Tags: heroes-of-hammerwatch

In Heroes of Hammerwatch, Mercenary mode allows you to play as a new character starting at level 20, and allows you to do multiple runs, in ever-increasing New Game+ runs.

As a part of this game mode, the player can purchase Life Insurance for 5000 x (NG+ Level) (For example, NG+5 would be 30,000g.) This allows your Merc's money to go back to your non merc run, ONLY IF you die, in your current run.

What is unclear to me, is, if you buy life insurance for a NG+1 Mercenary run, does the money that you had from previous runs apply to the money returned upon death to your town?

For example, John has 30,000g in his bank, while he's at town, having purchased everything he possibly could before his next run. If he buys Life Insurance for 10,000g, will his main characters recieve base 20,000 gold, the moment he dies in the upcoming run?

[image: Picture of Mercenary mode Life Insurance description]

Image attached for vague description of in game text on this.

Note that "That Adventure" could refer to just the NG+ run, or to the entire adventure of the Mercenary.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this myself given no reliable sources online.
I beat the game as a mercenary, then, with my 300 Ore and 70,000 gold, bought life insurance and purposefully died to the first creature at the start of my NG+ run.

I can now say, beyond a shadow of a doubt, that you will get none of it.

***The gold and ore provided by life insurance comes exclusively from that which you make in that New Game+ iteration ONLY.***